# Referring to an image inside a table with CSS

Tags: html, css

Okay, so this question could hardly be more basic, but... Why does this CSS rule not pick up the image inside the table?

```
# HTML
<table id="support-people"><tr><td>
<img src="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/img/1_0_1/cream/hi/news/news-blocks.gif" /></td>
</tr></table>
# CSS
#support-people img {
    width: 50px;
}
```

JSFiddle to show that the CSS is not being applied: http://jsfiddle.net/96F8H/

And if anyone can recommend me some kind of in-browser tool to pick up this kind of thing, bonus points...

Comment: #facepalm thanks for the answers, people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine. The problem was you had your CSS rule in the Javascript field. Here's a link with the things in the correct fields: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/zHvx9/.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is in the JavaScript box in your demo. [Here's a corrected version](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/96F8H/3/).

If the example in the question is your actual code, you'll need to wrap the CSS with style tags:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #support-people img { width: 50px; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly because you put the CSS in the Javascript part of JSFiddle.

Here's the working version with the CSS moved to the CSS section of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/96F8H/2/

Answer (score 0):

It works fine.  You put the css in the javascript section:

http://jsfiddle.net/96F8H/1/